# $|f(x)|<\infty$ a.e. implies $|f(x)|<M$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a measurable function in an interval $I=[a,b]$ and $|f(x)|<\infty$ a.e. in $I$. Prove that for any $\varepsilon >0$, there are positive number $M$ and a measurable set $A$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in A$ and $m(I \setminus A) \leq \varepsilon$.

It is obvious that $\lim_N \to \infty f^{-1}[-N,N] = [a,b]$. In fat, $f^{-1}[-N,N]$ increases to $[a,b]$. Thus, $\lim m(f^{-1}[-N,N]) = m([a,b])$. So, for any $\varepsilon$ there exists $M$ such that $m(f^{-1}[M,M]) - m([a,b]) < \varepsilon$ giving the result?

Comment: It looks good, is there a part you have any doubts?

Comment: Correct me if I'm  wrong but what you are trying to prove seems to be a  direct consequence of Lusins theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) - the only extrapolation needed then is that continuous functions on compact sets are bounded

Comment: How do you define limits of a sequence of sets?

Comment: Your answer is correct except that you wrote the inequality wrongly in the last step.